# A global key was used multiple time error when using snapshot flutter

Tags: flutter

[Error Facing][1]

This is the issue I am facing

Please review the code and let me know the error that I am getting thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKg7s.jpg

```
Future<String> saveImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
    await [Permission.storage].request();
    final time = DateTime.now()
        .toIso8601String()
        .replaceAll('.', "-")
        .replaceAll(':', "-");
    final name = "screenshot_$time";
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(bytes, name: name);
    return result['filePath'];
  }

  Future saveAndShare(Uint8List bytes) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final image = File('${directory.path}/flutter.png');
    image.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
    final text = "Save By Lottery App";
    await Share.shareFiles([image.path], text: text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try stop and rerun you application instead of hot reloading. That solved my problem.